# Is possible to discontinue chain of nodes?

Tags: tikz-chains

For example, the image:

[image]

can be drawn with following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
    start chain = going right,
base/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm},
 box/.style = {base, on chain, join=by ->}
                        ]
\coordinate (a) at (0,-1);
\node (n1)  [box]   at (0,0) {A};
\node (n2)  [box]   {B};
\node (n3)  [box]   {C};
\node (n4)  [base]   at (a -| n2) {D};
\draw[red,->]   (n3) |- (n4);
\draw[red,->]   (n4) -| (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, for some reason I like to have only one definition for nodes and draw above image again:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
    start chain = going right,
box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm,
              on chain, join=by ->}
                        ]
\coordinate (a) at (0,-1);
\node (n1)  [box]   at (0,0) {A};
\node (n2)  [box]   {B};
\node (n3)  [box]   {C};
\node (n4)  [box]   at (a -| n2) {D};
\draw[red,->]   (n3) |- (n4);
\draw[red,->]   (n4) -| (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is expected wrong:

[image]

*Question*: is it possible to say, that node "D" in above MWE is not on the chain? For example as

```
\node (n4)  [box, suppress chain]   at (a -| n2) {D};
```

similarly as it can be discontinued `join` between nodes in chain with definition of new option:

```
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
```

and used as

```
\node (n4)  [box, suppress join]   at (a -| n2) {D};
```

I looked in TikZ documentation, where is described `chainin` (page 5449), but didn't find anything with opposite action.

Comment: What is the desired output? Could you provide a picture?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I think he want to get the first picture with code similar to the second (without base/.style definition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},
  off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
  start chain = main going right,
  box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm, on chain, join=by ->}
  ]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,-1);
  \node (n1)  [box]   at (0,0) {A};
  \node (n2)  [box]   {B};
  \node (n3)  [box]   {C};
  \node (n4)  [suppress join, off chain, box]   at (a -| n2) {D};
  \draw[red,->]   (n3) |- (n4);
  \draw[red,->]   (n4) -| (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: off chain]

Note that the order matters here: `off chain` must be before `box`. You can then continue the chain, should you so desire.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
  start chain = main going right,
  box/.style = {draw, minimum size=7mm, on chain, join=by ->}
  ]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,-1);
  \node (n1)  [box]   at (0,0) {A};
  \node (n2)  [box]   {B};
  \node (n3)  [box]   {C};
  \node (n4)  [suppress join, off chain, box]   at (a -| n2) {D};
  \node [box] {E};
  \draw[red,->]   (n3) |- (n4);
  \draw[red,->]   (n4) -| (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: continuation]

Note, however, that the `chains` library is considered deprecated.

Comment: Dear @cfr, yes. I looking for something like this. Thank you very much! By the way, the `off chain` is sufficient. If the node is not in chain anymore, then macro`join` is not active in this node, so the `suppress join` is superfluous in this case :)